# How to make an HTML <button> vertifically fill a Table Cell with CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I make an HTML `<button>` vertifically fill a Table Cell with CSS?

I can use `width:100%` to make the button horizontally fill a Table Cell with CSS, but `height:100%` doesn't do anything.

For an example, please see:  http://jsfiddle.net/eA5fQ/

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be bit more clear..? What exactly do you want to with CSS?

Comment: Percentage height is inherited from the element's parent. If the parent's height is not defined there is no point of reference.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind a jQuery solution:

```
$('#button1').css('height', $('#button1').parent('td').height());
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VKnUr/1/)**

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to specify the height in pixels as in:

```
height: 100px;
```

Comment: Thanks Ken, that definitely works, but is there ANY way to do it via % so that it just takes over the entire area of the Table Cell it is in?

Answer (score 3):

Add `height:100%;` to your button and set height of your td tag in percents

Comment: yes set 100% on td and on button inside td. thanks that solved it

Answer (score -2):

If you use `min-height: 1px;` as well as `height: 100%;` it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jJbCd/8/

Comment: I'd love to be able to do with a %, but that's not working on my end (Firefox 4).  Any ideas why?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Height 100% works for me regardless if min-height is set or not.  Works in a TD tag, and the div. http://jsfiddle.net/jJbCd/9/   Also using FF4 (xp)

Comment: then you might not need that. :-) If it works without it, then take it out.